# Frame individual cells in a table

Tags: tables, framed

I'm aiming to make an RPG character sheet in LaTeX, but I'm having a little trouble with the boxes one usually asociates with this kind of thing. Is there a way to individualy frame table cells in some kind of automated manner? The MWE below has the distinct disadvantage that `fbox`s in different places are not guaranteed to line up.

Any solution would ideally allow the 'Wounds' `fbox` to be perfectly aligned (possibly with the use of `multirow` and `multicolumn`) with the other boxes. Also, more automated than the solution below (so if for some reason a number/description gets to big for a box, the whole sheet doesn't need redesigning).

The closest I've got to what I'm after, 
[image: MWE example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand\fpbox[2]{\fbox{\parbox{#1}{\centering #2}}}
\newcommand\fphbox[3]{\fbox{\parbox[c][#1][t]{#2}{\centering #3}}}
\newlength\cs
\setlength\cs{0.2cm}
\setlength\fboxsep{0.1cm}
\newcommand\hs{\hspace{\cs}}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}[c]{c@{\hs}c@{\hs}c@{\hs}c@{\hs}c}
\fpbox{1cm}{STR} & \fpbox{0.7cm}{14}& \fpbox{0.7cm}{0} &\fpbox{0.7cm}{0}& \fpbox{0.7cm}{0}\\[\cs]
\fpbox{1cm}{DEX}& \fpbox{0.7cm}{10} &\fpbox{0.7cm}{0} &\fpbox{0.7cm}{0}& \fpbox{0.7cm}{0}\\[\cs]
\end{tabular}
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\begin{tabular}[c]{ccc}
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{Wounds/Current HP}\\
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\fphbox{1.25cm}{4.4cm}{\hspace{0pt}}}
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe that it's easier to do this with Tikz.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not everything has to be a tabular, here's one alternative (a few helper macros could make the input a lot less verbose, depending on requirements)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\unitlength\textwidth
\divide\unitlength 420
\noindent\begin{picture}(420,80)

\multiput(10,40)(50,0){5}{\framebox(40,20){}}
\multiput(10,10)(50,0){5}{\framebox(40,20){}}
\put(260,10){\framebox(150,50){}}
\put(10,40){\makebox(40,20){\textbf{STR}}}
\put(60,40){\makebox(40,20){14}}
\put(110,40){\makebox(40,20){0}}
\put(160,40){\makebox(40,20){0}}
\put(210,40){\makebox(40,20){0}}

\put(10,10){\makebox(40,20){\textbf{DEX}}}
\put(60,10){\makebox(40,20){10}}
\put(110,10){\makebox(40,20){0}}
\put(160,10){\makebox(40,20){0}}
\put(210,10){\makebox(40,20){0}}

\put(260,60){\makebox(150,20){\textbf{Wounds/Current HP}}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

For example if you add

```
\makeatletter
\def\boxtext#1#2{%
\count@10
\@for\tmp:=#2\do{%
\put(\count@,#1){\makebox(40,20){\tmp}}%
\advance\count@50
}}
\makeatother
```

to the preamble you could enter the text in the boxes as:

```
\boxtext{40}{\textbf{STR},14,0,0,0}
\boxtext{10}{\textbf{DEX},10,0,0,0}
```

Comment: That is awesome! Is there a way to create a macro such that it calculates all the values based user input? E.g if I `\customput{0}{0}` it could place a box at (0,0) and (0,4)? The only way I can think of is counters, but then I'd have to create a counter for every instance of the macro (and use the `calc` package), kind of defeating the point of having the macro.

Comment: possibly suitable macro added to answer.

Comment: That's fantastic. I never knew the `picture` environment was so versitile!

Answer (score 3):

can also be done without a tabular and simple `\fbox` in a line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}p{8mm}}
\def\HLine{\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}\cline{5-5}\cline{7-7}\cline{9-9}}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{*5{|C|c}}\HLine
STR && 14 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\\HLine
\multicolumn{9}{c}{}\\[-0.5\normalbaselineskip]\HLine
DEX && 10 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\\HLine
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{ | p{4cm} |}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{ Wounds/Current HP }\\\hline
\strut\\
\strut\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and the same without a tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newcommand\MB[2][1cm]{\fbox{\makebox[#1]{\strut#2}}}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{7cm}
\MB[12mm]{STR} \MB{14} \MB{0} \MB{0} \MB{0} \\[10pt]
\MB[12mm]{DEX} \MB{10} \MB{0} \MB{0} \MB{0}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{4cm} 
Wounds/Current HP \\
\fbox{\parbox[c][1.5cm]{\linewidth}{\rule{\linewidth}{0pt}}}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]